# "Of course, it cost the companies some money, but also helps increase their profit." Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct "Of course, it **cost** the companies some money, but also **helps** increase their profit."? As I know, sometimes, we can use infinite verb with singular subject to emphasize things?

Comment: Are you intending to say it *has* cost* or *will* cost or (continuing) it *costs*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it is grammatical, but *cost* is not infinitive, but past: it is saying that it has already cost the companies some money. (Whether this makes sense or not depends on the context).

For some people, the past of *cost* is *costed*, and for them it would not be grammatical.

Comment: Surely the form _costed_ is always reserved for particular usages? AHDEL has: **cost** v. cost, costing, costs
_v.intr._
To require a specified payment, expenditure, effort, or loss: It costs more to live in the city.
_v.tr._
1. To have as a price.
2. To cause to lose, suffer, or sacrifice: Participating in the strike cost me my job.
3. [past tense and past participle costed] To estimate or determine the cost of: The accountants costed out our expenses. // RHK Webster's would be better (if it didn't misnumber).

Comment: Mixing tenses within a sentence (at least without repeating *it*) is one of the most basic instances of *ungrammatical*.

Comment: Edwin: Certainly I would use them as per your dictionary excerpt. I have had a look at the corpora, and BNC has 2 instances out of 50, and COCA 2 out of 27 where 'costed' is used as the past of meaning 1 above. So it appears that some people do use it as I've said, but fewer than I thought.

Comment: Tim: absolutely not. _I banged my knee and it hurts_. _I'm looking forward to seeing you, and will meet you at the Station at 2_. _It started yesterday and is still going on_.

Comment: @TimLymington I think we get that reading because we don't know what the antecedent of *it* is. If "it"= those companies having become part of an industry association, then it cost them money in the past, but helps them increase their profits now/generally. Or so it seem to me ...

Comment: @Araucaria : Here is the context of that sentence. "_I know someone are wondering about the good deal of dollars required to do charity. Of course, it cost the companies some money, but also helps increase their profit. When people see the good things that the companies do for the community, they believe more in the companies so they increasingly buy their products or apply to the companies._"

Comment: So it seems grammatical to me then! ("someone are" isn't though ...) :)

Comment: With that context, I believe _cost_ is simply an error for _costs_. The sentence is grammatical, but does not have a reading which makes sense there.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence sounds awkward because "cost" is past tense and "helps" is present tense.

To use **past tense** consistently, the sentence would be, "Of course, it **cost** the companies some money, but also **helped** increase their profit." In this example, both the cost and the benefit are in the past.

To use **present tense** consistently, the sentence would be, "Of course, it **costs** the companies some money, but also **helps** increase their profit." Present tense is correct if you are discussing a specific current example; present tense can also be used to discuss a theory or concept in general.

The original sentence, "Of course, it **cost** the companies some money, but also **helps** increase their profit" may be correct. The costs are in the past, but the companies are receiving the benefits in the present. The reader must know the meaning of "it" from the context. Even so, the sentence may still sound awkward.

If you want say the costs are in the past and the benefits are ongoing, here is another possibility: "Of course, it **cost** the companies some money, but **continues to** increase their profit."